# What does "break" mean ? libpython2-stdlib : Breaks: libpython-stdlib (< 2.7.15-2) but 2.7.12-1~16.04 is to be installed

Tags: python, apt

Env:python is 2.7.18,os is ubuntu 22.04

I use "apt-get install python-openssl", and error is below
may I know that does "Breaks" mean here. the errors looks confusing about version number

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpython2-stdlib : Breaks: libpython-stdlib (< 2.7.15-2) but 2.7.12-1~16.04 is to be installed
...
```

I have tried three, but still see this issue.

1)install libpytyon2-stdlib

2)install libpython-stdlib

3)remove libpython -- what ever.

Comment: In this context, "breaks" means "violates a versioning constraint". libpython2-stdlib declares that it's incompatible with old versions of libpython-stdlib (note the missing "2" here), but you're trying to install something that uses an old libpython-stdlib.

Comment: How to fix this depends on details of the individual packages -- it matters if python-openssl requires that old libpython2-stdlib because that's what it was built against, or if it requires it because it has a known bug with any newer one (and the control file lists that version as an explicit dependency). If it's the former, you can typically rebuild from source against newer dependencies. If it's the latter, you need to fix the bug that led to the dependency being created.

Comment: (also, this kind of problem generally doesn't happen at all in the first place if everything you're installing is from the same distro release; it's the kind of mess you get into when you're on distro version X and then you install a package that was built for distro version Y without rebuilding it from source, or you add an entry targeted to a different distro release to your sources.list file -- don't do that).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy.  I have removed libpython2-stdlib, and installed libpython-stdlib. but still has same issue when trying "apt-get install python-openssl"

Comment: Read the dependency tree. Could be that the chain coming from python-openssl leads to both, but I'm not running your distro (indeed, you haven't told me what distro you have, what your sources.list is, where this specific python-openssl is coming from, or _anything else_ that would allow running this down). Unless you include enough information to let someone else reproduce the problem in the question, we're not going to be able to speak authoritatively to solutions, and telling you how to read and interpret the error messages is all we have enough information to do.

Comment: BTW, perhaps the best way to provide a [mre] for this kind of problem is a Dockerfile that reproduces the issue when run; that way it's definitive that everything necessary is included in the question itself.

Comment: Ah. You're using packages from universe, not from the supported part of the distro. That makes you on your own. Personally, my approach is "don't do that"; when I need packages that aren't supported by Canonical on Ubuntu, I pull them in with [Nix](https://nixos.org/) instead of using apt at all.

Comment: (if I had to guess, which -- until you provide a Dockerfile -- I do: jammy universe has both `python2` packages and `python2.7` packages; you can't safely mix them)

Comment: ("removed libpython2-stdlib, and installed libpython-stdlib" doesn't work because clearly, python-openssl _requires_ libpython2-stdlib; a better place to figure out is why you can't find a new enough libpython-stdlib to not conflict)